# looping a $.getJSON with the alphabet

Tags: javascript, loops, getjson

I am looping a $.getJSON url with a SEARCHTERM.

I want to pro-grammatically also add each letter of the alphabet to the SEARCHTERM like such:

```
SEARCHTERM
SEARCHTERM
SEARCHTERM
SEARCHTERM a
SEARCHTERM a
SEARCHTERM a
a SEARCHTERM
a SEARCHTERM
a SEARCHTERM
SEARCHTERM b
SEARCHTERM b
SEARCHTERM b
b SEARCHTERM
b SEARCHTERM
b SEARCHTERM
```

Here is the code I am using to loop only the original "SEARCHTERM" without adding the alphabet on each end.

Here is the relevant javascript code:

```
var suggestCallBack; // global var for autocomplete jsonp
var keywordCount = 0;
$('body').on("click", '#submit', function() {
  $('#keywords').html('');
  var search_input = $("#keyword").val();
  var language = $("#edit-domain").val();
  callAPI(search_input, language);
  return false;
});

function callAPI(s, language) {
  $.getJSON("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?callback=?", {
    "hl": language, // Language
    //"ds":"yt", // Restrict lookup to youtube
    "jsonp": "suggestCallBack", // jsonp callback function name
    "q": s, // query term
    "client": "youtube" // force youtube style response, i.e. jsonp
  });
  suggestCallBack = function(data) {
    var suggestions = [];
    var languageText = $("#edit-domain option:selected").text();
    $('#keywordTable').show();
    $.each(data[1], function(key, val) {
      suggestions.push({
        "value": val[0],
      });
      $('#keywordTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + s + '</td><td>' + val[0] + '</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>');
      $('#keywordCount').text(++keywordCount);
      $('#keywordtext').text(s);
      $('#languageholder').text(languageText);
    });
  }
}
```

code for alphabet (if you need?)

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".split("");
_.each(alphabet, function(letter) {
  callAPI(search_input + ' ' + letter);
});
```

Summary: I want the relevant code to also add each letter of the alphabet to the beginning and end, while calling callAPI();